# "This field is required" when uploading multiple files in Django

Tags: python, django

This is my code. What it's supposed to do is allow the user to upload many files. The `afile` is the name I set in the `<input>` tag in the template, right?

Anyways, it simply says `this field is required` when I try to upload multiple files. I checked online and a common error is missing `request.FILES` in the form but I'm not missing that.

```
def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for afile in request.FILES:
                newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES[afile])

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notendur.views.list'))
```

edit - removed some irrelevant code

My form:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file'
    )
```

Comment: You should show us your form too

Comment: Why do you expect to upload multiple files from a single file input (where, in fact, you explicitly say 'Select *a* file')? Am I missing something?

Comment: I have multiple file inputs in my HTML. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Nope. You have to bind each form element (input, radio and so on) to a field in your form. Whether you define your fields statically (you have a fixed number of files the user can upload) or dynamically, it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting enctype to your form? -

```
<form method="post" class="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Without this, files won't be uploaded and usually throws the required error.

And for multiple files, try [formset factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).